# How to set value of my interface object from a different source

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httprequest, text-files

I have a json file with the following items:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "fileName": "1.txt", "title": "First Kidney Transplant in the Region"},
    {"id": 2, "fileName": "2.txt", "title": "Another article"}
]
```

I have an interface INewsArticle[] with the following objects

```
export interface INewsArticles{
id : number, 
fileName : string,
title : string,
content : Text
```

}

Everything except the content is loaded from my json file. What I want to do is to get the corresponding content of each article from a .txt file using one subscription and I don't know how to do that in typescript.

This is my subscription code:`this.svcNewsArticles.LoadArticles().subscribe(data => this._newsArticles = data);`

This is my service:

```
    private _srcArticles : string = "./assets/news-articles/newsList.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  LoadArticles() : Observable<INewsArticles[]>{
    return this.http.get<INewsArticles[]>(this._srcArticles);
  }
```

What I have currently is to get my INewsArticles[], bind it to the HTML with *ngFor and then call another method to subscribe to another request to load the content from my contents directory with an argument using the INewsArticles[].fileName. But this causes an infinite loop when tested on the console.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div id="divContainer" class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="20px" [style.marginTop.%]="_marginTop">
    <div id="divHeader" [fxHide]="_hideHeader">
        <h1>What's New?</h1>
    </div>
    
    <mat-card fxFlex.gt-sm="30%" fxFlex.lt-md="95%" *ngFor = "let article of _newsArticles">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title> 
                {{ article.title }}
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header> 
        
        <mat-card-content class="scrollable">  
            {{ getContent(article.fileName) }}
            <!-- <embed src='../../../../assets/news-articles/content/{{ article.fileName }}'> -->
            <!-- {{ getContent() }} -->
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card> 
</div>
```

Here's my subscription:

```
    getContent(fileName : string){
    this.svcNewsArticles.GetContent(fileName).subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}, err => {console.log(err)});
  }
```

Here's my service:

```
    GetContent(fileName : String){
    return this.http.get('./assets/news-articles/content/'+fileName, {responseType : 'text'}); 
  }
```

I am new to this, please bare with me.

Comment: The issue is not clear to me. I suggest you proceed step by step. What do you get when executing thei `this.svcNewsArticles.LoadArticles().subscribe(data => this._newsArticles = data)`? Do you actually read the articles and place them in `this._newsArticles`? What happens when you execute this `this.svcNewsArticles.GetContent(fileName).subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})` with an existing file name? Do you log something on the console? Let's start from here.

Comment: It is not considered best practice to call a method in an interpolation `{{}}`. See the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#expression-best-practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both HTML requests together using any of the higher order mapping operators such as switchMap or mergeMap.

Something like this:

```
  posts$ = this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postUrl).pipe(
    mergeMap(posts =>
      forkJoin(
        posts.map(post =>
          this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${post.userId}`).pipe(
            map(user => ({
              title: post.title,
              userName: user.name
            }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

You can find a working Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-posts-user-mergemap-deborahk

Applying that to your code, it would look something like this:

```
  this.http.get<INewsArticles[]>(this._srcArticles).pipe(
    mergeMap(articles=>
      forkJoin(
        articles.map(article=>
          this.http.get('./assets/news-articles/content/'+article.fileName, {responseType : 'text'}).pipe(
            map(content=> ({
                id : article.id, 
                fileName : article.fileName,
                title : article.title,
                content : content
            }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

NOTE: This has not been syntax checked or validated. Please provide a small working StackBlitz example for a more specific and syntax checked answer.

This code first gets all of the articles. It then uses mergeMap to process the articles and automatically subscribe to the inner Observables. The forkJoin allows us to process each article in the array of articles using articles.map.

We then issue the http request for the article content and map the retrieved data into the desired interface.

The result is an Observable<INewsArticles[]> that includes the content. You can then do simple interpolation binding in your template.

UPDATE: You can shorten the syntax a bit using object destructuring:

```
  this.http.get<INewsArticles[]>(this._srcArticles).pipe(
    mergeMap(articles=>
      forkJoin(
        articles.map(article=>
          this.http.get('./assets/news-articles/content/'+article.fileName, {responseType : 'text'}).pipe(
            map(content=> ({
                ...article, 
                content : content
            }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

The `...article` syntax copies all of the article properties. Then you only need to add the `content`.

Comment: This worked very well. I just had to change my content object datatype from Text to String because it comes out to be incompatible. Also, thank you for the advice on the interpolation; will keep that in mind. Thank you.